# How to get the result of async / await function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I would like to return an object from the the async / await *function A* to pass it to another function.

Currently what I get as a result is `Promise{ <pending> }'` or undefined.

function A:

```
const parseRss = data => data.forEach(rssLink => {
    const getFeed = async () => {
        try {
            const feed = await rssParser.parseURL(rssLink.rss);
            const emailContent = {
                emailBody: {
                    title: feed.title,
                    content: []
                }
            }

            feed.items.forEach(item => {
                feedObj.emailBody.content.push(`${item.title} : ${item.link}`)
            });
            return emailContent;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    };
    return (async () => {
        return await getFeed();
    })();
});
```

Function B:

```
    try {
        const data = await getDataWithRss();
        const emailData = await parseRss([{rss:'http://reddit.com/.rss'}]); // emailData is undefined
       return formatEmail(emailData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
```

How do I return *emailContent* from function A to use it in function B?

Thanks!

Comment: ```await``` must be inside an ```async``` function. Is function B an ```async``` function?

Comment: And `parseRss` is returning `data.forEach(...)`. `forEach` will always return `undefined`

Comment: yes, function B is async

Comment: What happens if you have multiple URLs? Do you want to return an array of `emailContent` (one from each URL)  in the resolved promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made `getFeed` as async, no need another async. You are looping through, so return an array of promises. Once the you call use `Promise.all` to resolve. Since there could be multiple urls to fetch.

```
const parseRss = (data) =>
  data.map((rssLink) => {
    const getFeed = async () => {
      try {
        const feed = await rssParser.parseURL(rssLink.rss);
        const emailContent = {
          emailBody: {
            title: feed.title,
            content: [],
          },
        };

        feed.items.forEach((item) => {
          feedObj.emailBody.content.push(`${item.title} : ${item.link}`);
        });
        return emailContent;
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
    return getFeed();
  });
  try {
    const data = await getDataWithRss();
    const emailData = await Promise.all(parseRss([{rss:'http://reddit.com/.rss'}])); // emailData is undefined
   return formatEmail(emailData);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

await will not work inside a forEach loop. Use a for...in loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

actually, getFeed() is not necessary inside inner scope, you can use async in map callback:

```
const parseRss = data => data.map(async rssLink => {
    const feed = await rssParser.parseURL(rssLink.rss);
    const emailContent = {
        emailBody: {
            title: feed.title,
            content: []
        }
    };

    feed.items.forEach(item => {
        feedObj.emailBody.content.push(`${item.title} : ${item.link}`)
    });

    return emailContent;
});
```